# How to send result of AlertDialog fragment using viewModel?

Tags: java, android-alertdialog, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a custom dialog fragment that communicate to its parent using intent. (I've copied it from somewhere). This uses old framework for communicating that some of its methods such as `onActivityResult`, `getTargetFragment()` has been deprecated now.

I know that one can replace these deprecated methods with new methods e.g. [How to replace setTargetFragment() now that it is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64869501/6576302)
but going such long way just for getting a yes or no result?!

Is there a simple way for doing this? I tried to use ViewModel but doesn't worked!

My ViewModel try: AlertDialogViewModel.java

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class AlertDialogViewModel extends ViewModel {


    private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> mAlertDialogResult = new MutableLiveData();
    public LiveData<Boolean> getAlertDialogResult() {
        return mAlertDialogResult;
    }
    public void setAlertDialogResult(boolean mResult) {
        mAlertDialogResult.setValue(mResult);
    }


}
```

And inside of MyAlertDialog.java:

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {

    AlertDialogViewModel mViewModel;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                .setTitle(Title)
                .setMessage(MESSAGE)
                .setPositiveButton("YES", (d, b) -> onResult(true))
                .setNegativeButton("NO", (d, b) -> onResult(false))
                .create();
    }

    private void onResult(boolean result) {
       mViewModel.setAlertDialogResult(result);
    }
    private static void showResult(Framgment fragment) {
       dialog.show(fragment.getParentFragmentManager(), null);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work when I want toast it as:

```
MyAlertDialog.showResult(this)
AlertDialogViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AlertDialogViewModel.class);
        model.getAlertDialogResult().observe(this, result-> {
            Toast(this, ""+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize your dialog fragment view model. You need to get the same instance as the one being used in the hosting Activity or parent Fragment.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Assumes requireContext() returns the Activity this dialog is shown in
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireContext()).get(AlertDialogViewModel.class)

    return new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(Title)
            .setMessage(MESSAGE)
            .setPositiveButton("YES", (d, b) -> onResult(true))
            .setNegativeButton("NO", (d, b) -> onResult(false))
            .create();
}
```

Then make sure you're getting the same instance in your Fragment:

```
AlertDialogViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireContenxt()).get(AlertDialogViewModel.class);
model.getAlertDialogResult().observe(this, result-> {
    Toast(this, ""+result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

Lastly, what is `dialog` and why is this static?

```
private static void showResult(Framgment fragment) {
   dialog.show(fragment.getParentFragmentManager(), null);
}
```

Comment: Tnks for Answer. `showResult` is used to show dialog in actitvity/fragment. for example `MyAlertDialog.showResult(this)` will show an alert dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't show toast message! It also doesn't crashes. and is error-free.

Comment: But `dialog` isn't declared in your sample code.

Comment: Yeah, I know, during minimizing the codes I forgot to declare it as `MyAlertDialog dialog = new MyAlertDialog ();`.

Comment: @dominicoder: can one use `getParentFragment()` instead of `requireContext()` if the parent is a fragment? will this work?

Comment: No, because `requireContext()` returns a `Context` and `getParentFragment()` returns a `Fragment` which is not a `Context`.